# Material UI Tabs how to change orientation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So far i tried custom css with breakpoints selector but i want to make it more **material** why without custom style and state? is there any example?

> is there better approach advise would be appreciate

```
 <Tabs
   value={this.state.tab.value}
   orientation={"horizontal"} <-- to change vertical or horizontal depends on
```

Comment: You seem to have used orientation as you should have, what is you problem with this approach?

Comment: you also don't need the curly brackets when using quotes there

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import withWidth, { isWidthUp } from "@material-ui/core/withWidth";
    
    let condTabOrientation;
      if (isWidthUp("sm", props.width)) {
        condTabOrientation = "vertical";
      } else {
        condTabOrientation = "horizontal";
      }
    
    
    <Tabs
    orientation={condTabOrientation}     
     />
    
    export default withWidth() (UserAccount);
```

see more on breakpoints doc

https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#withwidth-options-higher-order-component